# How do I find the uniques and the count of rows for multiple columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a file with 136 columns. I was trying to find the unique values of each column and from there, I need to find the number of rows for the unique values.

I tried using df and dict for the unique values. However, when I export it back to csv file, the unique values are exported as a list in one cell for each column.

Is there any way I can do to simplify the counting process of the unique values in each column?

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
    column_headers = list(df.columns.values)
    
    df_unique = {}
    df_count = {}
            
    def approach_1(data):

        count = 0
        for entry in data:
            if not entry =='nan' or not entry == 'NaN':
                count += 1
        return count
    
    for unique in column_headers:
        new = df.drop_duplicates(subset=unique , keep='first')
        df_unique[unique] = new[unique].tolist()
        
    csv_unique = pd.DataFrame(df_unique.items(), columns = ['Data Source Field', 'First Row'])
    csv_unique.to_csv('Unique.csv', index = False)
    
    for count in df_unique:
        not_nan = approach_1(df_unique[count])
        df_count[count] = not_nan
    
    csv_count = pd.DataFrame(df_count.items(), columns = ['Data Source Field', 'Count'])
```

Comment: `.unique()` is more simplify ->`len(df[col].unique())` is the count

Answer (score 0):

.unique() is simpler ->len(df[col].unique()) is the count

```
import pandas as pd
dict = [
{"col1":"0","col2":"a"},
{"col1":"1","col2":"a"},
{"col1":"2","col2":"a"},
{"col1":"3","col2":"a"},
{"col1":"4","col2":"a"},
{"col2":"a"}
]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)

result_dict = {}
for col in df.columns:
    result_dict[col] = len(df[col].dropna().unique())

print(result_dict)
```